# add Array using for loop (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm recreating a hangman game where I create a random word and conceal this with "*". i.e if the word is "monkey" then the array should be ["*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "_"].

With the following code, the alert ends up displaying ",,,,,*" or "*".
I've tried searching for the answer, tried .push method and rearranged the code to no avai.

also, this code is example code out of a beginners book so I'm not sure if it's simply just outdated now.

Appreciate if anyone can shed some light on how I could get this to work with basic beginner syntax.

```js
// Attempt 1:

var words = [
    "javascript",
    "monkey",
    "amazing",
    "pancake"
];

var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
console.log(word);

var answerArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++); {
    answerArray[i] = "_";
}

alert(answerArray);
// outputs ",,,,,,_"

///Attempt 2:
//Same code as above but with:

alert(answerArray.join(" "));
// outputs single "_"

///Attempt 3
//as above but with:

var answerArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++); {
    answerArray.push("_");
}

alert(answerArray.join(" "));
// outputs single "_"
```

Comment: I've just noticed that when I type "_" multiple times as I've done in the question above, they disappear leaving only the last one...

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++);` remove the `;` your loop wasn't working correctly because you wrote the for statement wrong

Comment: _"I've just noticed that when I type "\_" multiple times [...]"_ - that's because the underline character is part of the markdown syntax, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: such a rookie error! thanks so much everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

First Quick tipp use let instead of var. Then in your first attempt in the initialization of the for loop, you have a semicolon after the closing bracket. This terminates the statement and the for-body (between the {}) gets not executed. so remove that semicolon and you're good to go

Answer (score 0):

```
      const words = [
          "javascript",
          "monkey",
          "amazing",
          "pancake"
       ];

      var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
      console.log(word);

      var answerArray = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
              answerArray[i] = ",";
      }

      console.log(answerArray[0])

      alert(answerArray);
```

Remove the semicolon in for loop and you are ready to go.

```
      [ ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon after the for loop declaration and before the body of for loop. This semicolon is making your for loop to end as soon as it get declared.

```
var words = [
"javascript",
"monkey",
"amazing",
"pancake"
];

var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
console.log(word);

var answerArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
answerArray[i] = "_";
}

alert(answerArray);
```